# How to get list of objects from sub folder of Amazon S3 bucket using golang?

Tags: go

How do I get the list of objects from a sub folder of an Amazon S3 bucket using golang?

I tried:

```
svc := s3.New(session.New(), &aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-east-1")})

params := &s3.ListObjectsInput{
    Bucket: aws.String("bucket"),
}

resp, _ := svc.ListObjects(params)
for _, key := range resp.Contents {
    fmt.Println(*key.Key)
}
```

I got the list of all the objects in the bucket, but I need only the list of objects in a subfolder.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add Prefix parameter in params

```
params := &s3.ListObjectsInput {
    Bucket: aws.String("bucket"),
    Prefix: aws.String("root/subfolder"),
}
```

will list objects from subfolder/

Answer (score 3):

in order to access the folders (they are not really folders, as s3 is an object storage)
you have to provide the Prefix and Delimiter attributes to ListObjectsInput
say that you have s3://foo/bar
you can provide the "foo/bar" prefix with the '/' delimiter to get all the subobjects