# ListObjects always returns list of 1000 object. Can we list objects sorted by date?

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using `aws-doc-sdk-examples/go/example_code/s3` example code to list out objects in my s3 bucket.

Following two folders are created by default in bucket:

```
bucket-logs/AWSLogs/accountxxx/CloudTrail-Digest/
bucket-logs/AWSLogs/accountxxx/CloudTrail/
```

Both folders have sub folders like

```
/us-region-1/[year]/[month]/[day]/
```

I am using below GoLang code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) != 2 {
        exitErrorf("Bucket name required\nUsage: %s bucket_name",
            os.Args[0])
    }

    bucket := os.Args[1]

    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-east-1")},
    )

    svc := s3.New(sess)

    resp, err := svc.ListObjects(&s3.ListObjectsInput{Bucket: aws.String(bucket), })
    if err != nil {
        exitErrorf("Unable to list items in bucket %q, %v", bucket, err)
    }

    for _, item := range resp.Contents {
        fmt.Println("Name:         ", *item.Key)
        fmt.Println("Last modified:", *item.LastModified)
        fmt.Println("Size:         ", *item.Size)
        fmt.Println("Storage class:", *item.StorageClass)
        fmt.Println("")
    }

    fmt.Println("Found", len(resp.Contents), "items in bucket", bucket)
    fmt.Println("")
}

func exitErrorf(msg string, args ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, msg+"\n", args...)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

The above code always returning 1000 object from `bucket-logs/AWSLogs/accountxxx/CloudTrail-Digest/` Whereas I want to list objects from `bucket-logs/AWSLogs/accountxxx/CloudTrail/` folder.

Can we do this. Can we filter list object sorted by year/month/date?

Any help ?

**EDIT:**

I am running the Go programm using the below cli command

```
./s3_list_objects bucket-logs
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you run the program in the command line?

Comment: @Mark - I am using this command to run the program  `./s3_list_objects bucket-logs`

Comment: 1000 entries is the usual limitation of AWS' api's. You ought to use chaining keys to get the rest of the data. Also, the keys on S3 are always listed in lexicographic order, if you need a different sort order, you must sort them on your side.

Comment: @oakad - Thanks for the info, helpful. Let me try your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to add `prefix` in `ListObjectsInput`. Check out this `https://stackoverflow.com/a/43737253/1225070`

```
params := &s3.ListObjectsInput { 
    Bucket: aws.String("bucket"), 
    Prefix: aws.String("root/subfolder"), 
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes I have already read this. I am trying the same but still facing issues.

Comment: I finally able to resolve my issue. TY for your answer.

Comment: @elegant-user happy to help